# Facebook og:url redirect loop

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

So, we run a news site and the URLs for specific articles might change after the article has been published (the URL usually contains the article title).

To keep track of Facebook shares even when the URL changes, we've add the og:url property with the unique URL for the article (which is basically our domain, followed by the article ID).

The problem is, this unique URL redirects to the article page, so when I share the "pretty" article URL, I get a redirect loop.

Any ideas on how to workaround this issue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you're setting the og:url parameter to anything other than the canonical URL for that content, you're misusing it.

The `og:url` tag tells Facebook where to go for the canonical metadata for a URL - if you're then redirecting elsewhere from that URL, it wasn't really the canonical URL - you should have set the og:url value to wherever is at the end of the redirect cycle, and put the article metadata there

if you need to track specific placements or clicks of the like button and the referral traffic from those, there's a ref parameter you can use for that which is passed back to you in the referral traffic, it's documented here: https://developers.dev.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/#faqref

Comment: Actually Google states:

    "Can rel="canonical" be a redirect? Yes, you can specify a URL that redirects as a canonical URL. Google will then process the redirect as usual and try to index it."

In my opinion, Facebook interprets the og:url field incorrectly.

Source: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.se/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html

Comment: Facebook will follow `rel="canonical"` meta tags too, but there's also the `og:url` mechanism which has the same effect and also specifies the canonical URL for that Open Graph object; there's no defined behaviour if you have a meta rel = canonical and an og:url pointing to different URLs, i suspect facebook will follow the og:url and google will follow the meta rel="canonical"